# How to achieve this style in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been try but this functionality I haven't been able to solve.

These 4 divs are child div of the parent div

We need to create so that the 3 child divs are in a column but the last div that is an image will be in a separate column and right aligned inside the parent div.

Could you please help me find answer to this question.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: Have you code something? I'll suggest to read [ask] and [mcve]. After that you can search on google something about flexbox or grid layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily use a [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) to achieve this. I guess you want something like this, right:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "Div-1 Div-4"
    "Div-2 Div-4"
    "Div-3 Div-4";
}
.grid-container div {padding: 10px;}
.Div-4 { grid-area: Div-4; background: #f90;}
.Div-1 { grid-area: Div-1; background: #ccf;}
.Div-2 { grid-area: Div-2; background: #cfc;}
.Div-3 { grid-area: Div-3; background: #fcc;}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="Div-4">Div 4</div>
  <div class="Div-1">Div 1</div>
  <div class="Div-2">Div 2</div>
  <div class="Div-3">Div 3</div>
</div>
```

Here your parent container is `.grid-container`. I used [Interactive CSS Grid Generator | Layoutit Grid](https://grid.layoutit.com/) to generate this code.

**Preview**

[image: preview]